# Collect kotlin flow until condition

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I need to collect infinite Kotlin Flow, check for its data and stop until I get desired String or once timeout pass. I need to emit expected String when collected desired string or throw an exception in case of timeout. I simulate infinite Kotlin flow in this way:

```
    fun String.toInfiniteByteArrayFlow(): Flow<ByteArray> {
        return callbackFlow {
            trySend(this@toInfiniteByteArrayFlow.toByteArray())
            awaitClose()
        }
    }
```

I wrote test which should throw an exception, because stream contains string "ok" and we expect "error", so it should throw an exception after 1 second, because desired string "ok" was not collected. Here it is:

```
        @Test
    fun `should not collect unexpected data within given duration for infinite flow`() = runTest {
        assertThrows<NotCollectedExpectedMessageException> {
            runCatching {
                ExpectedFlowCommandWithRemovingTrailingCharacters().expectOn("ok".toInfiniteByteArrayFlow(), "error").collect()
                advanceTimeBy(2000L)
            }.onSuccess {
                fail("Should not be here")
            }.onFailure {
                assertThat(it).isInstanceOf(RuntimeException::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my implementation:

```
class ExpectedFlowCommandWithRemovingTrailingCharacters {

    suspend fun expectOn(flow: Flow<ByteArray>, expectedCommand: String): Flow<String> {
        val collectedSoFar = StringBuilder()
        return try {
            withTimeout(1000L) {
                val emptyFlow = flow {
                    while (true) {
                        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(200L)
                        emit("")
                    }
                }
                flow {
                    flowOf(flow.map { String(it) }, emptyFlow).flattenConcat().transformWhile {
                        ensureActive()
                        if (it != "") {
                            collectedSoFar.append(it)
                            if (collectedSoFar.toString() == expectedCommand) {
                                emit(collectedSoFar.toString())
                                false
                            } else {
                                true
                            }
                        } else {
                            true
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            throw RuntimeException(
                "Timeout during collecting data. Collected $collectedSoFar, expected $expectedCommand", e
            )
        }
    }
```

I'm concatenating two flows: one flow with real data and second flow with "simulated" data only for checking for timeout on each 200ms (so my flow is cancellable). Unfortunately, flow ends immediately instead of throwing exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that first flow to do? It turns the input String into a byte array that it emits to the collector, then simply suspends forever, never emitting again, but never finishing either. Is that what you intended? I don't understand what the point of doing that would be.

Comment: The purpose is to wait for specific String, which is coming up from ByteArray flow within given timeframe. I'd like to simulate situation, in which expected string never comes, so flow should throw an exception because of timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now what you're trying to do. A Flow that concatenates byte arrays into a single String until the total string matches `expectedCommand`, and then emits that single value. But the Flow throws a RuntimeException if it doesn't emit within one second. (This is maybe a little odd, since it's a Flow that is known to only ever return one item. Might make more sense as a Deferred.)

What I can see is that you wrap a cold flow in `withTimeout`, which doesn't really make sense. A cold Flow will be returned immediately, so there's no opportunity for anything to time out. You haven't called any suspend functions inside the `withTimeout` block.

Likewise, with the try/catch, you will never catch a CancellationException here, since this function immediately returns the cold flow without ever having called a suspend function that cooperates with cancellation.

So, I think in both cases you missed that wrapping *the task of creating* a cold flow in `withTimeout` or `try`/`catch` doesn't do anything to what happens when that Flow is eventually collected. You need to implement these using Flow operators and/or builders because these must happen when the returned flow is being collected.

Also, you mention you create another fake flow to concatenate with so your flow is cancellable, but all the terminal Flow operators are cancellable anyway, so you don't need that or `ensureActive()`.

Would this work for your purposes?

```
suspend fun expectOn(flow: Flow<ByteArray>, expectedCommand: String): Flow<String> = flow {
    val collectedSoFar = StringBuilder()
    try {
        withTimeout(1000L) {
            flow.map { String(it) }
                .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                .onEach { collectedSoFar.append(it) }
                .first { collectedSoFar.toString() == expectedCommand }
                .let { emit(it) }
        }
    } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        throw RuntimeException(
            "Timeout during collecting data. Collected $collectedSoFar, expected $expectedCommand", e
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `flow.timeout(duration)`

Comment: I think that would work fine. I probably wasn't familiar with that operator at the time I wrote this.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to put the String collected so far into the exception message.